# Piranha CMS - Login issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

I have just added Piranha CMS to an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 site but am having a strange issue.

If I am logged into the site and then try to access site.com/manager and enter the piranha login details then the page just refreshes and nothing happens (trying with an incorrect password gives me an incorrect password message but correct login details just refreshes page)

If I try accessing site.com/manager without being logged into the site then it logs me in OK the piranha manager area.

Any ideas why this is? Ideally I'd like the user to only need to login once is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Piranha CMS doesn't integrate with other authentications. For now the only solution is to keep the user accounts separate like you noticed. This feature has however been planned for a couple of years but hasn't been implemented due to various reasons.

Pulling out the authentication mechanics imposes a lot of changes on the database schema **and** makes setting user priviliges for specific pages much harder.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but it is not clear how to approach it. To simplify I'm using clean MVC template with authentification and then install CMS with nuget following getting started doc for existing web sites. So how can I do or where to read on the ways to make site work as it was for end users and also have CMS working side by side with this login issues? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this can be supported with a small change to the handling of the Piranha user class to support both FormsIdentity and ClaimsIdentity. I've posted the fix on the Piranah GitHub Issue log - I'm sure it will get included in a build in the future, but you might want to give the fix a try. With this change I can support MVC4/5 and Piranha (and HTTPS as well).

I use OWIN identity management in my application and switching from my application to Manager correctly asks me to login (Piranha uses Forms). This isn't a problem and I have no problem with the need to have separate logins between application users and content managers.

I noticed a problem under Https where the LocalUserProvider class was expecting to get a FormsIdentity back from the HttpContent.Current.User.Identity but in many cases it was getting a ClaimsIdentity. This caused it to refuse the login and keep cycling round the login form.

I locally modified the LocalUserProvider to add the following method;

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Piranha explicitly uses FormsAuthentication - this method is used to replace a calls to HttpContext.Current.User.Identity in this 
        /// module which would ordinarily return the users Idenity as an ClaimsIdentity, and the Name part of the ClaimsIdentity is the login name
        /// not the Forms Authentication Guid expected by Piranha. The OWIN and Forms can co-exist side by side, but when Piranha gets the users
        /// identity, it expects to get a Forms Identity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity extractFormsIdentityFromHttpContext()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
            {
                System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
                if(claimsPrincipal != null)
                {
                    return claimsPrincipal.Identities.OfType<System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity>().FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and use it like this;

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets if the current user is authenticated.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsAuthenticated {
            get {
                System.Security.Principal.IIdentity formsIdentity = extractFormsIdentityFromHttpContext();
                if (formsIdentity != null && formsIdentity.IsAuthenticated) {
                    try {
                        // Check if this user has a Guid id.
                        var id = new Guid(formsIdentity.Name);
                        return true;
                    } catch { }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This means the LocalUserProvider will always deal with the contexts FormsIdentity explicitly and has the happy side effect of allowing manager login to work under https.

Hope its a useful suggestion

Comment: You should at least post the link to the issue log, you referring. Even better would be the fix, since links can become invalid :)